How to stop disruption of an Android phone wireless hotspot
I have a PC that connects to the Internet using the wireless network of a Nokia XR21 hotspot.
The network is being frequently disconnected maybe by a jammer.
How can I stop the disruption?

If your phone supports it use 5GHz for the Hotspot. On 2.4GHz everybody is allowed to send (Bluetooth, other analogue and digital devices). On 5GHz the frequencies are usually exclusive to Wifi (depends on your country).

Also on Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1862481/356789

The jammer thing is unlikely. Possibly the Android device got hot and thus affected the hotspot performance.

Please don't double post across sites - if this is more applicable to Android Enthusiasts vs Superuser please request for it to be migrated.

It is very very unlikely to be a jammer.  Some ISPs have a time limit for hot-spotting.  I think that is what you are encountering.  There is no way to get around that.
